# No .NET Core and .NET Standard options when creating project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

When I'm creating new project in Visual Studio I see only one option under .NET Core category and no .NET Standard category at all. There should be more options ex. library and "ASP.NET Configuration File".

I can create .NET Core projects by "dotnet" command in command line and when I'm opening project in Visual Studio I see ".NET Standard" as target framework.

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.8.1 on Windows 10 Pro.
I tried reinstalling .NET Core and Visual Studio, changed .NET Core to x86 and back to x64, restarted Windows about 10 times, cleaned env path, repaired VS in VS installer but I've seen no effect.

[image: VS 2017 Screenshot]

Comment: Are you sure you you have the desired workloads in VS Installer?

Comment: I have checked all components in "ASP.NET and web development" section, all in ".NET desktop development", all in ".NET Core cross-platform-development" and some others. I don't really know which are necessary.

Comment: The screenshot looks fine. Show us the options you have in Windows Desktop.

Comment: Under Windows Desktop: https://imgur.com/a/mvuVd5T